# C# chart sort doesn't work

Tags: c#, sorting, charts

I am trying to sort C# chart data but sort method doesn't work. Chart is still the same.

```
    chart1.Series.Clear();
    chart1.Series.Add("My Data");

    chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IsUserEnabled = true;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.Count; i++)
    {
        DataPoint dp = new DataPoint(i, frequency[i]);
        dp.AxisLabel = alphabet[i].ToString();
        chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(dp);
    }

// I've tried to sort by different ways including to make IComparer class
chart1.Series[0].Sort(PointSortOrder.Ascending,"Y");
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you had the types for the objects on there.  Which library is chart1 coming from?

Comment: I can't reproduce. Here the code sorts the data points just fine!

Comment: Maybe you have different .Net framework version? I've .NET framework 4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried the sample and you are right it does not work. Could not find the perfect solution even after reading the documentation for the control. However, if the X Axis value does not matter for you, you could try the below code

```
for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.Length; i++)
{               
    DataPoint dp = new DataPoint();
    dp.AxisLabel = alphabet[i].ToString();
    dp.YValues = new double[] {frequency[i]};
    chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(dp);                
}
```

The sorting works as expected when you feed the data points in this manner.